# Change width of progress bar via jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a few progress bars that uses the bootstrap framework.  I have a Ajax call that requests to update the bars, but I am not sure how to change all of the parameters.

Before I used bootstrap, I used an image that could easily be adjusted using the width.. But with this, I am not sure. Here is my progress bar.

```
<div class='progress'>
  <div class='progress-bar progress-bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='60' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 60%;'>
    <span class='sr-only'>60% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the Javascript that I WAS using with the old images:

```
$("#img_enperc").css('width', $("enperc", xml).text());
$("#img_enopp").css('width', $("enopp", xml).text());
```

It is probably simple, but since there is about 130 people a day that gets on using all different browsers, I want to make sure I get this right...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.progress-bar` class is what will control the width of the colored area of the bar, so to target it with the snippet you used to use, just do this:

`$(".progress-bar").css('width', $("enperc", xml).text());`

The problem you will run into with this method is that the `.progress-bar` div uses a percentage based width to calculate its size, so you will need to convert the output of `$("enperc", xml).text()` to a percentage.

`$(".progress-bar").css('width', $("enperc", xml).text() + "%");`

This of course depends on the value of the number you are producing is between 1-100.  Otherwise you will have to derive your own percentage value.

If you are wanting to use multiple progress bars, just give the `.progress` wrapper a unique ID, and target them that way:

```
<div id="progressMain" class='progress'>
  <div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar'>
    <span class='sr-only'>60% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then:

`$("#progressMain .progress-bar").css('width', $("enperc", xml).text());`

Just remember to remove the default inline width style on the `.progress-bar` div, along with the duplicated class name.

Comment: Cool, looks like what I wanted. I will try this out later this week and mark it as answer if it works!

Comment: @alexander7567 Absolutely!  I'll keep my eyes open for notifications if you have any questions :)

Comment: @stat30bliss, it worked after a little tweaking.. I just had to add  + "%", which I guess is what you meant by "so you will need to convert the output of $("enperc", xml).text() to a percentage.". It was already in a percentage value, just not with a % sign after it. But after addin that, it worked fine. Even has a cool animation. Thanks!

Comment: @alexander7567 yep that's exactly what I meant, and I will update my answer with that snippet.  Glad it was helpful!